# Get KML style in OpenLayers 5

Tags: javascript, openlayers-5

I have some code in an application that access the style of a selected feature in a KML layer. It was working in OpenLayers 3.1. I have now upgraded to 5.3.0 and it stopped working. See the relevant lines below:

```
var featStyle = feature.getStyleFunction().call(feature, map.getView().getResolution());
var strokeWidth = featStyle[0].getStroke().getWidth();
var strokeColor = featStyle[0].getStroke().getColor();
var fillColor = featStyle[0].getFill().getColor();
var fillOpacity = (Math.round(fillColor[3] * 100));
```

The line:

```
var featStyle = feature.getStyleFunction().call(feature, map.getView().getResolution());
```

Produces an error visible in the developer console:

```
TypeError: o.getGeometry is not a function[Learn More] KML.js:943
    a KML.js:943
    myFunctionName file.php:5371
    onclick file.php:1
```

I can't find anything in the documentation or examples that shows how to properly access the KML style data for a given feature (not an entire layer/source). Is there a new way to do this or did I miss something?

Could it have to do with this?: https://github.com/IGNF/geoportal-sdk/issues/2 Plugged into Google translate it seems to say something about no longer storing style properties inside each feature but it does not seem to say where they are stored...

The KML is valid and displays on the map properly. I just can't seem to find a way to access the style data anymore.

Comment: I think it should be `var featStyle = feature.getStyleFunction().call(map.getView().getResolution());`  Only layer style functions need to be passed a feature.

Comment: Just tried it, still giving me the same error but your code does make more sense as the feature should not have to be accessed twice.

Comment: This was the code I was successfully using before the update: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/3262

Comment: Yes, the feature is an argument of `.call` and not the style function itself.  I've just tested logging the feature styles from this demo https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/kml.htm  In OL4 it needs `feature.getStyleFunction().call(feature, map.getView().getResolution());` which can also be coded as `feature.getStyleFunction().bind(feature)(map.getView().getResolution());`  I changed to the OL5 full build and it now needs `feature.getStyleFunction()(feature, map.getView().getResolution());`  so it seems the code no longer uses `this` and feature has to be passed to the main function.

Comment: @Mike you are a lifesaver! Please post as an answer and I will accept it. Works great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OpenLayers 3 and 4 a feature style function takes only a resolution argument but internally uses `this` so the function or call must be bound to the feature:

```
feature.getStyleFunction().bind(feature)(map.getView().getResolution());
```

or

```
feature.getStyleFunction().call(feature, map.getView().getResolution());
```

In OpenLayers 5 feature style function are similar to layer style functions and require the feature to be passed as an argument:

```
feature.getStyleFunction()(feature, map.getView().getResolution());
```